# Finding points where a matrix-valued function results in singular result

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the function
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\
f(x)=x^2I +xA+B
$$
where $I$ is the identity and $A$ and $B$ are given matrices. For which values of $x$ is the resulting matrix singular?

It would of course be easy if $A$ and $B$ commuted but I would like to have an answer for the most general case possible.

Comment: Without the $x^2$ term, this is the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom while that is true I fail to see how that helps in solving the promblem I'm having...

Comment: it doesn't.  It does, however, indicate that any solution here is not going to have any "nice form" in the most general case.